# How to group a numeric variable in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the data that has numeric variable A. I want to make groups for A to have something like B.

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 9, 15, 30, 100, 0.2, 0.003, 
95, 18), B = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 
10L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your expected output? a sketch or another dataframe would be fine.  Do you want an additional variable which is a grouping variable for `A`?

Comment: what is your expected output? this is very unclear.

Comment: My output should look like B

Comment: obviously, 0-10 (1), 11-20 ( 2), 21-30 (3)....... etc.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to create B from A? it looks like you want something like

```
data$A %/% 10
[1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  3 10  0  0  9  1
```

or

```
(data$A %/% 10)+1 
[1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  4 11  1  1 10  2
```

Comment: can I customize the ranges? for example telling R that (0-10  = 1), (11-20 = 2 ) and so on?